# does bx500 support host memory buffer (HMB)?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

does crucial ssd bx500 support host memory buffer (HMB)? and if yes how to activate it in windows 10/11?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HMB is an NVME technology and requires an NVME 1.2 host and drive. It is not a part of the SATA specifications from what I can find. From [ITIGIC: What is the Host Memory Buffer in NVMe SSDs and How Does it Work?](https://itigic.com/host-memory-buffer-in-nvme-ssds-how-does-it-work/)

> The NVMe 1.2 specification introduced a new feature called Host Memory Buffer or HMB

The [BX500](https://www.crucial.com/products/ssd/bx500-ssd) is a SATA SSD. It is limited to approximately 500MB/s by the SATA specification. Even if SATA did support HMB it's speeds are more than enough for most modern SSDs to completely saturate the link and to put up enough of a good show on operations that *might* make use of the cache that it still isn't really needed.

As an example for the Toshiba RC100, an NVME device that can use HMB, [it performs well above SATA speeds even with the HMB disabled](https://www.anandtech.com/show/12819/the-toshiba-rc100-ssd-review/7). With SATA limiting the connection HMB is going to provide nearly no benefit.